# Prefill html form input fields using google sheet

Tags: html

I am trying to build a form which can be automatically filled means without any manual work. i am trying to create a form which will help in to find details of a student with just selecting its name from drop down box. Users just have to select the name, and its other details like age, hometown, father name will be automatically prefilled in the input fields. I have stored the details of every student on a google sheet. url of that google sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NYFJrAZwJFoOo2fMXWW0EbOfYMZ9Ku0Ubdz50l2rxaI/edit?usp=drivesdk

now, i just have to link my html page and this google sheet to autofill input fields. given below is my html code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>details of student</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form>
<select>
<option>Amit</option>
<option>Yash</option>
<option>Abhay</option>
<option>Ajay</option>

<input type="button" id="autofill" value="autofill">
</input>

</select><br /><br />
  Age<input type="number"></input>
<br /> Home town<input type="text"></input>
<br /> Father<input type="text"></input>
     
     
     
     </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

when the user will click input button (id=autofill), the fields should get filled with the details of the selected name in drop down box. i tried on google to find any relevant sample or example. but didn't find any such thing. hopefully, coders at Stackoverflow would help me to complete this task. can anyone please help me in completing this task.

Comment: Could you give us a little more information? You have tags for `javascript`, `php`, `ajax` but your code is only `HTML`. Which languages are you using in this project? Do you want everything to happen in the Frontend (by using` javascript` for example) or do you have a backend server (in `php`, for example)?
Also, have you tried anything so far? The question is a little bit broad.

Comment: @bruno I can use JavaScript, php and html for this project. I tried Google to find something for my project. But found nothing related to this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of processing that data;

One is to download the file manually every time you run the code. This is bad.

Second is to use the Google Sheets API. I'm guessing you are using php. So you can take a look at Google Documentation for Sheets API:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Please read the documentation well. it will guide you.

Note that you can find Google API PHP client here

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: I tried reading Google API. But it is too complicated. Please can you provide a working example.  I am not much specialist in coding. Thanks in advance.